# Getting error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encrypt'" when trying to encrypt text

Tags: python, encryption

I was trying to make a fun little program with Python:

```
#secret text be like:
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
g = open("ygr.data")
message = g.readlines()

key = Fernet.generate_key()

# Instance the Fernet class with the key

fernet = Fernet(key)

h = open("key.keysbois", "w")
h.write(str(key))

# then use the Fernet class instance
# to encrypt the string string must must
# be encoded to byte string before encryption
encMessage = fernet.encrypt(message.encrypt())

f = open("totallysecrettext.rushe", "w")
f.write(encMessage)
```

I might be being dumb, but I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encrypt'` when I try to run it. Any suggestions?

Also, is it ok to use weird file extensions (i.e. `file.rushe`, `file.data`, `file.key`)

Comment: Why do you expect the list `message` to have a method named `encrypt`?

Answer (score 1):

You're reading in the file's content by using `readlines()`. This returns a *list* of lines from the file.

```
message = g.readlines()
```

You then try to call `encrypt` on this *list*, which doesn't make sense - since you're already calling it on the `fernet` object:

```
fernet.encrypt(message.encrypt())
               ^-- this is a list of lines from the file - not what you want
```

Instead, read the file's content using just `read()`. You also have to make sure you read the file in binary format, so that you get bytes you can send to fernet:

```
g = open("ygr.data", "rb")
message = g.read()
```

.. then encrypt the content:

```
encMessage = fernet.encrypt(message)
```